# Having trouble using the_title() and the_permalink() in a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to write a new plugin since I haven't been able to find one that does exactly what I want with the extensibility that I desire. The goal of the plugin is to be able to use a simple shortcode to display an image slider that automatically populates with your blog's latest posts.

I've got the basic plugin files ready and the shortcode implemented and tested. Now I'm trying to get the plugin to pull in the blog's latest posts, but I'm running into a bit of a snafu. When I use the_title() and the_permalink() they display outside of the code I'm trying to contain them in. Further, the_content() is displaying once with the_permalink() and the_title() and then a second time where it's supposed to.

You can see the behavior [here](http://acommunityofwomen.com/slider/).
Here's the code I'm using:

```
function slyd( $category, $slydcount ) {
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;  // Create $tmp_post to empty $post once Slyd is done with it

    $args = array(
        'category'    => $category,
        'numberposts' => $slydcount
    );
    $slydposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $slydposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        $post_permalink = the_permalink();  // Get the post's permalink
        $post_title = the_title();          // Get the post's title
        $post_content = the_content();      // Get the post's content - will write code to get excerpt later
        return '<h2><a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . $post_title . '</a></h2>\n'
        . '<p>' . $post_content . '</p>';
    endforeach;
    $post = $tmp_post;                      // Empty $post once Slyd is done with it
}

// Create the shortcode
function slyd_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // $atts        ::=        array of attributes
    // examples:               [slyd]
    //                         [slyd category='slide']
    //                         [slyd slydcount='5']
    //                         [slyd theme='default']

    /* Retrieve attributes set by the shortcode and set defaults for
       unregistered attributes. */
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'category'   =>  '',        // Which category(s) to display posts from
        'slydcount'  =>  '5',       // How many Slyds to display
        'theme'      =>  'default'  // Which Slyd theme to use
    ), $atts ) );

    return "<p>category = {$category}, count = {$slydcount}</p>"
    . slyd( $category, $slydcount );
}

add_shortcode( 'slyd', 'slyd_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `the_title` will print out (echo) the title. You can pass extra parameters to the function in order to get it to just return the title, like so:

```
<?php the_title('', '', false); ?>
```

But it's even better to just use `get_the_title` instead – and the same goes for `get_the_content` and `get_permalink` as well.

Comment: Awesome, this was definitely the solution. I read in the WP Codex Shortcodes page something about using return instead of echo, I just wasn't sure how to solve the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: That should be `get_permalink` though. That's probably one of the most annoying inconsistencies in WordPress.

Comment: Simon's right, it is get_permalink. I had to do a little more research in the codes to figure that one out.

Comment: I don't see inconsistency in WP I only see lack of research when people say such things and or downvote. All functions with get_ are return functions, great for use outside of the loop.